# Multiple items in one basket that get processed at different rates on completion of checkout

Tags: website-design, user-behavior, e-commerce, checkout, shopping-cart

Does anyone have any good ideas on how to solve the problem of having multiple products in one order (basket) that are processed at different rates once the user completes their purchase?

An example of this, in my opinion, may be something like the way amazon may have to handle it. they have multiple vendors selling through one point. How do they show there users the status of individual items? Are there any best practice ways to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: When you say "processed at different rates", do you mean different costs or different speeds?

Comment: sorry, i meant the speed at which the order is processed by the seller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have already pointed out, Amazon have a good way of handling this, and I would follow their example.

You have a single order that shows what you ordered, but you fulfil that order in multiple packages each of which may ship at a different time, from a different location, using a different delivery method, at a different cost, etc.

[image]